# opening a html file in a web-view in android studio

Tags: android, html

I added every thing to my app but it keeps opening the page that said page not found even if i add a URL for google or any other link.

I look at most of the solutions for the same question but none of them worked (allowing internet access, allowing local access, changing the link to android asset, ......)
Any way hers my code hope you can help:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url="http://www.google.com";
        WebView home  = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.homeweb);
        home.loadUrl(url);
        home.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        home.clearCache(true);
        home.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alex.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/homeweb" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know it's very simple in code but I'm still new to programming HTML in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below code for showing html code in browser,

```
  WebView view = new WebView(getActivity());
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    ((LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_about)).addView(view);

    view.loadData(Html.fromHtml(put your url here), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

put html file in assets folder then write following code in activity

```
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

  webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_file_name.html");
```

remove these line from xml code

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

also remove code from activity

```
 home.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 home.clearCache(true);
 home.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Programs run from top to bottom.So your problem is just the arrangement of your code.
In the onCreate method, use this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webView = (webView) findViewById(R.id.webView_id);
webSettings websettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//After configuring all the required settings then you load your url
webView.loadurl("https://www.google.com");
webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
```